# After registering custom post type in theme functions.php , menu labels like: `All Posts` and `Add New` appears after refresh the page

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-post-type

I have a problem with Custom Post Types when I try to register it in my Theme's core (functions.php)

After adding new user role with custom capabilities and registering the new custom post type for example `car` with `cupability_type => [ 'car', 'cars' ]` everything goes well but the menu labels `All Cars` and `Add New` appears after page refresh. Same approach works fine with plugin but it doesn't work with Theme. Below my code:

```
<?php

add_action( 'after_switch_theme', 'prefix_add_new_user_role' );
//add_action( 'admin_init', 'prefix_add_new_user_role' );

function prefix_add_new_user_role() {
    add_role( 'car_instructor', __( 'Car Driving Instructor', 'textdomain' ),
        [
            'read'          => true,
            'edit_posts'    => false,
            'delete_posts'  => false,
            'publish_posts' => false,
            'upload_files'  => true,
        ]
    );

    $roles = [ 'car_instructor', 'administrator' ];
    foreach ( $roles as $user_role ) {
        $role = get_role( $user_role );
        //phpcs:ignore
        $role->add_cap( 'read' );
        $role->add_cap( 'edit_others_posts' );
        $role->add_cap( 'create_cars' );
        $role->add_cap( 'read_car' );
        $role->add_cap( 'read_private_cars' );
        $role->add_cap( 'edit_car' );
        $role->add_cap( 'edit_cars' );
        $role->add_cap( 'edit_others_cars' );
        $role->add_cap( 'edit_published_cars' );
        $role->add_cap( 'publish_cars' );
        $role->add_cap( 'delete_others_cars' );
        $role->add_cap( 'delete_private_cars' );
        $role->add_cap( 'delete_published_cars' );
    }
}

add_action( 'init', 'prefix_add_custom_post_type' );

function prefix_add_custom_post_type() {
    //phpcs:ignore
    $labels = [
        'name'                  => __( 'Cars', 'textdomain' ),
        'singular_name'         => __( 'Car', 'textdomain' ),
        'menu_name'             => __( 'Cars', 'textdomain' ),
        'name_admin_bar'        => __( 'Cars', 'textdomain' ),
        'add_new'               => __( 'Add New', 'textdomain' ),
        'add_new_item'          => __( 'Add New Car', 'textdomain' ),
        'new_item'              => __( 'New Cars', 'textdomain' ),
        'all_items'             => __( 'All Cars', 'textdomain' ),
        'search_items'          => __( 'Search Cars', 'textdomain' ),
        'parent_item_colon'     => __( 'Parent Cars', 'textdomain' ),
        'not_found'             => __( 'No Cars Found', 'textdomain' ),
        'not_found_in_trash'    => __( 'No Cars Found In Trash', 'textdomain' ),
        'featured_image'        => _x( 'Car Cover Image', 'Overrides the “Featured Image” phrase for this post type. Added in 4.3', 'textdomain' ),
        'set_featured_image'    => _x( 'Set cover image', 'Overrides the “Set featured image” phrase for this post type. Added in 4.3', 'textdomain' ),
        'remove_featured_image' => _x( 'Remove cover image', 'Overrides the “Remove featured image” phrase for this post type. Added in 4.3', 'textdomain' ),
        'use_featured_image'    => _x( 'Use as cover image', 'Overrides the “Use as featured image” phrase for this post type. Added in 4.3', 'textdomain' ),

    ];
    //phpcs:ignore
    $args = [
        'labels'             => $labels,
        'public'             => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui'            => true,
        'show_in_menu'       => true,
        'query_var'          => true,
        //phpcs:ignore
        'rewrite'            => [ 'slug' => 'cars' ],
        'capability_type'    => [ 'car', 'cars' ],
        //phpcs:ignore
        'capabilities'       => [
            'edit_post'          => 'edit_car',
            'edit_posts'         => 'edit_cars',
            'create_posts'       => 'create_cars',
            'edit_others_posts'  => 'edit_other_cars',
            'publish_posts'      => 'publish_cars',
            'read_post'          => 'read_car',
            'read_private_posts' => 'read_private_cars',
            'delete_post'        => 'delete_car',
            'read'               => 'read',
        ],
        'has_archive'        => true,
        'hierarchical'       => false,
        'menu_position'      => 60,
        'menu_icon'          => 'dashicons-car',
        //phpcs:ignore
        'supports'           => [
            'title',
            'editor',
            'thumbnail',
        ],
        //phpcs:ignore
        'taxonomies'         => [ 'category', 'post_tag', ],
        //phpcs:ignore
        'map_meta_cap'       => true,
    ];

    register_post_type( 'car', $args );
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated